# Why Xampp (on windows) can't load a php page but using Ubuntu(virtualhost,apache2) everything is fine?

Tags: php, html, laravel-4

So, I created a simple registration page in laravel 4.2 using bootstrap.
I've tested it via xampp on windows, and on ubuntu too, but in xampp i got this:

[image: this]

and on ubuntu this:

[image: this]

I don't really know what could be the problem with xampp.

In master page i have the following in head section:

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') ?>">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo asset('css/jquery-ui.css') ?>">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo asset('css/main.css') ?>">
```

Comment: Can you share the line where you are including the CSS file or Bootstrap

Comment: press f12. look for network errors. Looks like missing stylesheets.

Comment: whats the generated path from the echo asset call? View source, and share the link thats generated.

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/laravel/server.php/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/laravel/server.php/css/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/laravel/server.php/css/main.css">`

Comment: I think this is the problem, but i don't know how to pass the correct path to scripts and stylesheets

Comment: instead of using the asset function, can you just include the path: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: I used `{{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.css') }}` and it's fine in both :) thank you all

Comment: @LeviMali please add your solution as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I used `{{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.css') }}` and it's fine in both